# How to get asm to jump to a variable address in c?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

Right now, I call the jump instruction with inline assembly in c as follows:

```
int register eax asm("eax") = addr; // addr is a memory address
asm("jmp *%eax");
```

I want to do it without having to set any other register values (e.g. I want to do is something like this):

```
asm("jmp *(addr)");
```

What is the right way to do that? That is, how can I "insert" a c variable into the asm call?

Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, Intel x86 64-bit processor, gcc version 4.7.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

["Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands"](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm)

```
asm volatile("jmp *%0" : : "r" (addr));
```

Comment: This gives the following error:
`my.c:450:2: error: output operand constraint lacks '='
my.c:450:2: error: output operand constraint lacks '='
my.c:450:2: error: invalid lvalue in asm output 0`

Comment: @Sefu: Right, my bad.

Comment: **Note that it's not generally safe to `jmp` out of an inline asm statement without `asm goto` ([GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels))**.  Or at least a `__builtin_unreachable()` after the asm statement to let the compiler know that execution doesn't come out the other side, and it can't safely defer a store or something until after the asm.